# Centering an image in the center of the card

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I'm trying to center the image in the middle of my card.

I tried applying additional styles like traditional HTML tags to center it, but no luck so far.

[image: Image looks like 1 e w]

```
<article class="photo">
   <img src="https://mirror-api-playground.appspot.com/links/filoli-spring-fling.jpg"   style="  width:50%; 
      height:50%; 
      background:url(logo.png) center center no-repeat;">
   <div class="overlay-gradient-tall-dark"></div>
   <section>
      <p class="text-auto-size">Spring Fling Fundraiser at Filoli</p>
   </section>
</article>
```

https://gist.github.com/stanzheng/8489645

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<article class="photo">
   <div style="width:100%; text-align:center">
      <img src="https://mirror-api-playground.appspot.com/links/filoli-spring-fling.jpg" style="width:50%; height:50%;">
   </div>
   <div class="overlay-gradient-tall-dark"/>
   <section>
      <p class="text-auto-size">Spring Fling Fundraiser at Filoli</p>
   </section>
</article>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you need the width:100% on the div?   Unless the default CSS changes the div behavior, divs are *block* elements, thus will already be width:100%... I think only the text-align:center is necessary.  Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shanonvl/9L2FP/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by giving `text-align` property to the parent element. **[Live jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pemLR/)**

```
<article class="photo" style='text-align:center;'>
```